# Sentence in javascript but variable

Tags: javascript, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

i'm working with titanium and alloy. 
I need run a JavaScript sentence like

```
$.D7F15.visible="true";
```

but D7F15 must be a variable, like

```
var mifranja="D7F15";
```

How i can run this??

some help please??

Comment: i need some like this

Comment: '$.'+mifranja+'.visible="true"';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [bracket notation to access object property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation)

```
var mifranja="D7F15";
$[mifranja].visible="true";
```